# How do I fix Disk 0 size 0 B?

Tags: windows-10, installation, diskpart

I'm reinstalling windows 10 on my laptop. I never get past choosing where to install it because it always says that I can't install it because it's only 0 MB. While trying out a possible solution that I found, i encountered  a problem. It said "Diskpart has encounteres an error: Incorrect function. See the System Event Log for more information."

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you can boot up a Linux LiveCD, take a look at that drive.  You may need to initialize it so Windows thinks it is starting from a clean factory-fresh disk.    Also, the disk might have failed.  Can you provide some context here?  Why are you reinstalling Win10?

Answer (score 1):

In general if the physical drive size is 0 MB (or some other unrealistically small size) it's due to the drive suffering from a firmware issue and it should be replaced.

A hard drive is essentially a computer-within-a-computer.

[image]

As in a PC, the CPU/MCU communicates with system RAM (SDRAM) and BIOS ("ROM"). Just like a PC's BIOS, the HDD's ROM contains code for POST-ing and booting. The ROM code enables the MCU to test and communicate with its peripheral devices.

During bootup, the ROM code is unpacked into SDRAM. Likewise, the BIOS in a PC also unpacks itself into system memory. In a PC the BIOS code bootstraps the system from a bootable storage device. Similarly, the ROM loads "overlays" from a reserved System Area (SA) on the platters. These overlays then enable the drive to communicate via its SATA interface.

If the hard drive is unable to load these overlays, it's OS or the firmware it will typically display a fraction of it's size or 0 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the disk is functioning correctly, you need to "clean" it to remove any improper formatting information.

1. Boot from your Windows installation media
2. Choose Repair your computer
3. Choose Troubleshoot
4. Choose Command Prompt
5. Run `diskpart`
6. Type `list disk` and identify the disk number of your fixed disk
7. Type `select disk X` where X is the disk number from step 6
8. Type `clean`. **Warning:** This will erase the selected disk!
9. Type `exit` and then restart your computer and try installing Windows